# How to find an element with webdriver-io that matches multiple data- attributes?

Tags: e2e-testing, webdriver-io

The [webdriverio docs for $ or findElement](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$.html) aren't that extensive, I'm used to other e2e tools, hence the confusion, to find an element that has both attributes I want to achieve something like:

```
const element = $('[title="HOW TO USE?", data-text="HOW TO USE?"]');
```

Is this the correct syntax?

WEBDRIVERIO version: 5.6.6

Comment: you can pass xpath/css selectors to `$()`. What you are asking is some basic css selector. See also https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try as below.

const element = $('[title="HOW TO USE?"][data-text="HOW TO USE?"]');